# $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to show that the following set is an algebra: Let $X$ be some set. We define a system of sets $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ by $$\mathcal{C} = \{ S \subseteq X : \text{for all } E \subseteq X \text{ we have } \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap S) + \mu^*(E \cap S^c),$$ where $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(X) \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}_{+} $ is an outer measure, i.e.

1. $\mu^*(\emptyset) = 0$,
2. For all $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$, $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(B)$,
3. For any sequence $A_i \subseteq X, i =1,2,\ldots$ we have $$\mu^*\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_i).$$

Show that $\mathcal{C}$ is an algebra.

So I only need to show three things:

1. $X \subset C$
2. $A \subset C \implies A^c \subset C$
3. $A,B \subset C \implies A \cup B \subset C$

1: Letting $X=S$, we see that in order for $X \subset C$ to be true, $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap X) + \mu^*(E \cap \emptyset) = \mu^*(E \cap X) = \mu^*(E).$$ Since $\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E)$ is trivially true, $X \subset C$.

2: Suppose $A \subset C$. Then $\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c)$. Now consider $S=A^c$, then $$\mu^*(E \cap A^c) + \mu^*(E \cap (A^c)^c) = \mu^*(E \cap A^c) + \mu^*(E \cap A) \leq \mu^*(E),$$ so $A^c \subset C$.

3: I'm a little stuck with 3. We have that $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c),\\ \mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap B) + \mu^*(E \cap B^c).$$ How can I use this to show that $$\mu^*(E) \geq \mu^*(E \cap (A \cup B)) + \mu^*(E \cap (A \cup B)^c)?$$ I have tried doing some adding and subtracting but nothing seems to bring anything. Some other trick maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhhh, I got it.

Solution:
We use the fact that $\mu^*$ is sub-additive, so $\mu^*$ of any union is less than or equal to the sum of its parts. So we have $$\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*( E \cap A^c)\\ = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap (A \cup B)^c ) + \mu^*( E \cap (B \setminus A))\\ \geq \mu^*(E \cap (A \cup B)^c) + \mu^*(E \cap (A \cup B)).$$